# Why does Proxy.create return "TypeError"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I was playing around with ECMAScript 6 proxies in Chrome (requires the "Enable Experimental JavaScript" flag). I pasted the following code in the console (taken from [here](http://www.kevinwestern.org/blog/2012/11/07/ecmascript-6-a-quick-look-at-proxies/)):

```
var loggable = function(obj, logger) {
  return Proxy.create({
      get: function get(receiver, prop) {
          logger.info('Getting ' + prop);
          return obj[prop];
      }
  });
};

var person = { name: 'Alice', age: 22 };
person = loggable(person, {
  info: function info(str) {
      console.log(str);  
  }
});
```

The result was:

```
Getting splice
Getting splice
"TypeError"
```

Can anyone explain why the `splice` property of `person` gets accessed twice, and why we get `"TypeError"`?

Comment: So you're just doing `person.splice` on the proxy object? I don't get that behavior in Firefox, but I haven't tested in Chrome yet.

Comment: ...just tested in Chrome, and again it doesn't produce the result you describe when doing `person.splice`.

Comment: Now I see that I missed that you were testing in the console. Here's my take on it... Who cares if the console does weird stuff, as long as your code works as expected where it actually counts! Console implementations all suck to varying degree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem can be simplified to:

```
Proxy.create({
    get: function get(receiver, prop) { console.log(prop); }
});
```

Chrome probes the object in an attempt to discover its type. This triggers the `get` trap, and can be revealed by adding `console.log(arguments.caller.callee);` in the `get` trap.

```
    get: function get(receiver, prop) { console.log(arguments.caller.callee); }
```

yields http://pastebin.com/Fr3ACkJ8. The most significant line is:

```
        if (typeof obj.splice === "function" && isFinite(obj.length))
            return "array";
```

which shows an attempt to access the `splice` property, caught by your `get` trap. In the end `TypeError` is logged because Chrome is unable to convert the proxy into a representable object.

Comment: Ah, so OP was testing code in the console. I really wish people wouldn't do that... or at least would test in a pure environment before posting questions. +1